# How to reload .bash_profile in Linux with C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I used system("source ~/.bash_profile") to reload it, but it does not work. Is there any other function or code to reload the bash with C++ program in linux?

Comment: The shell will be the parent process of your program (sometimes) so it's not clear what it is you are trying to achieve.  Please enlighten us.

Comment: @trojanfoe In my C++ program, I am trying to add variables in .bash_profile in Linux, and use it. For example, I append .bash_profile with ofstream (ex) $SOMEPATH) and try to use that variable ( ex) system("cd $SOMEPATH")), but terminal cannot read that variables I added so I add another system function to reload .bash_profile and not working :(

Comment: `system(command)` in a C++ program is not the same as running `command` in a shell script - it starts a *new* shell that executes `command` and then exits.

Comment: If you want to run a child process and affect its environment you don't need to modify `.bash_profile`; you can do that with `setenv()` and then any process started with `fork()` and `exec()` will inherit those variables.  In fact the order should probably be `fork()`, `setenv()`, `execl()` so that the parent (your process) environment stays clean.

Comment: maybe use popen() ?

Comment: @pepicon That's a more detailed description of the method you're trying to use to achieve what you want. What is the ultimate thing you want to achieve by doing this?(If you just want to change the working directory, try `man -k 'working directory'` in a terminal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `source ~/.bash_profile` works, if you're actually *in* the process running the `bash` shell you want to affect.

When you started your C++ program, that started up in a *different* process, a child of the `bash` process, and therefore unable to modify the environment of that `bash` process.

And, in fact, it's even *worse* than that since a `system()` call in a C++ program almost certainly runs *another* process to do that work, so it's twice removed from the `bash` process.

And, in fact, it's worse even than *that,* since `source` is a `bash` internal command, meaning you'd have to start up a `bash` shell to execute it :-)

Hence, what you end up with is the following hierarchy of processes, all of which can really only affect their own environment, not anything above them:

```
  original-bash
        |
   C++-program
        |
bash-run-by-system
```